# inheriting parent background color with alpha makes child background color different. why?

Tags: html, css

inheriting parent background color with alpha makes child background color different. why?

When parent is having some background color with alpha(rgba) and child is inheriting parent background color why is child color different from parent?

```css
.parent {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: rgba(2, 107, 227, 0.2);
}

.child {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">

  <div class="child"></div>

  <h1>This is a Heading</h1>
  <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
</div>
```

Why is child background color is different from parent background-color?

[image]

Comment: Because child lays on the parent - its like you put two layers of colored glass over each other - its darker on the overlays.

Answer (score 4):

Take two pieces of coloured, transparent plastic. Put one on a sheet of white paper. Put the other on top of it. The result is darker. This is the same effect.

---

80% of the parent's background colour is `rgb(2,107,227)` and 20% is whatever **its** parent is.

80% of the child's background colour is `rgb(2,107,227)` and 20% of the result of the calculation in the previous paragraph.

---

```css
div {
  border: solid black 1px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 5em;
  width: 5em;
  position: absolute;
}

.one {
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
  top: 1em;
  left: 1em;
}

.two {
  background: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.5);
  top: 1em;
  left: 4em;
}

.three {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.5);
  top: 3.5em;
  left: 2.5em;
}

span {
  background: black;
  z-index: -1;
  height: 10em;
  width: 1em;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0em;
  top: 0;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-name: slide;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-direction: alternate;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}

@keyframes slide {
  from {
    left: 0em;
  }
  to {
    left: 9em;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="one"></div>
<div class="two"></div>
<div class="three"></div>

<span></span>
```